# Newsletter ads are misformatted in iPad Safari

Tags: bug, design, ipad, mobile-safari

A screenshot for your consideration:

[image]

This is in Safari on an iPad running iOS 10.3. It's happening on all sites I've visited so far to spot-check, including some beta SE sites and some SE sites with their own designs.

Comment: FHOC? That's new... ;)

Comment: Just keeping you on your toes, @ShadowWizard. Constant vigilance!

Comment: Haven't seen that. When did that happen?